# Column name changed while appending

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe `frame`. I want to change the column name and append to another dataframe sliced from `frame`. But column name changed after appending

```
colm=['ERR3618659', 'ERR3618660', 'ERR3618661', 'ERR3618662', 'ERR3618663', 'ERR3618664', 'ERR3618665', 'ERR3618666', 'ERR3618667',
 'ERR3618668', 'ERR3618669', 'ERR3618670']

#Slicing the required portion
partA=frame.iloc[:, :2]
TPM=frame['TPM']
FPKM=frame['FPKM']

#Assigning column names to tpm and fpkm
FPKM.columns=[colm]
TPM.columns=[colm]
```

when I print TPM here column names are appearing correclty like `ERR3618659` `ERR3618660` `ERR3618661` ....

```
tpm_tab = pd.concat([partA,TPM], axis=1, join='inner')
```

But appended column look like `(ERR3618659,) (ERR3618660,) (ERR3618661,).....`.
I don't know how does the bracket`()` and comma `,` came from

Comment: Is the issue because colm is already a list of column names, but when you assign the column names to FPKM and TPM you then wrap it inside another list?

Comment: but when i print FPKM and TPM the column names are appearing correctly. The column name changes only when I concatenated the two frames

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].